# Improve estimation of effect-size (difference between two distributions) by using LDA distance to decision boundary

Tags: effect-size, group-differences, discriminant-analysis

Before getting to the point, I will provide some context:

- I have a dataset that includes $176$ quantitative neuroimaging markers ($m_i$ for $i=1,...,176$) and several categorical variables representing different disease phenotypes (among them we find categories $A$ and $B$).
- Initially, I performed a linear discriminant analysis (LDA) to compute the signed distances to the decision boundary between categories $A$ and $B$. Instead of applying LDA to the entire dataset of neuroimaging variables, I used a certain number of principal components in order to minimize the predictive error.

Apart from using the signed distances for classification purposes, I would like to use them to estimate the difference between the $m_i$ distribution for categories $A$ and $B$. I want to improve the sample estimator, which was originally computed using the effect size based on the Wilcoxon-Mann-Whitney test.

One possible solution I have considered is assuming that $m_i$ and the distance to the decision boundary between $A$ and $B$ follow a bivariate (e.g. normal or t) distribution (a different distribution for each category). Under this assumption, I would simulate observations from these distributions and calculate the effect size using both the original observations and the simulated ones. This approach could make sense, as it allows to incorporate the information from the signed distances (they take into consideration predictive aspects) into the estimation of the marker distribution differences.

Does it make sense at all? I would really appreciate hearing alternative approaches! If you need more details, I will be happy to provide them!

Thank you in advance!